# Select single random item from list of items

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, random

I have a query that returns list of results. I want a single random item from that list.

```
var query = (from...
            where...
            select q).Random(1); //Something like this?
```

How to do this? Suppose there is 1 item i want that one to be selected. If there are more then i want one of those to be selected in a random order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var query = (from...
            where...
            orderby Guid.NewGuid()
            select q).First();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could utilise the [`Shuffle`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1262619/259656) example posted in [Randomize a List in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt-in-c-sharp) in conjunction with the LINQ `Take` method to create an extension method on an `IList<T>`, you'd need to `ToList` your selection prior to calling `Random`, unless you moved that inside the extension.

```
public static List<T> Random<T>(this IList<T> list, int takeNumber)
{
    return list.Shuffle().Take(takeNumber);
}

public static List<T> Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list)  
{  
    Random rng = new Random();  
    int n = list.Count;  
    while (n > 1) {  
        n--;  
        int k = rng.Next(n + 1);  
        T value = list[k];  
        list[k] = list[n];  
        list[n] = value;  
    }

    return list;
}
```

Comment: This will execute on the client rather than in the SQL.

Answer (score 0):

This Shuffle Method is better than others answers. it will not cost any performance issue when chaining and it's still LINQ.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> TakeRandom<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int count)
{
    return source.Shuffle().Take(count);
}

public static IEnumerable<T> Shuffle<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    return source.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid());
}
```

Usage:

```
var query = (from...
        where...
        select q).TakeRandom(1);
```